# GraphServiceClient Select control not working as expected

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

The following piece of code returns a lot more fields than the ones I´ve specified.

```cs
var user = await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"]
                .Request()
                .Select(u => new {
                    u.DisplayName,
                    u.JobTitle,
                    u.GivenName,
                    u.PostalCode,
                    u.Identities
                })
                .GetAsync();
```

I am following the instructions from ms docs stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-requests?tabs=CS). What am I missing?

Comment: It returns `User` object whatever `Select` is; however, `DisplayName`, `JobTitle` and other *properties mentioned* will be filled in (not just `default` values). Same for `Expand` - if not mentioned the corresponding reference will be just `null`

Comment: Oh, I understood that a shortened user object would be returned from the specified fields instead, otherwise, I can´t see the point in using '.Select' as these properties are already returned by default.

Comment: The point is that we *query* AAD (Azure Active Directory) and when we use `Select` the query will be briefer (shorter JSON returned, easier query) and faster: you want just `5` properties from, say, `100` to be actually queried

Comment: Got you! Makes all the sense, thanks!

Comment: Btw, is there any pitfall on how to get the custom attributes of a given user? The following piece of code cant get the job done:


 `// var extensions = await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"].Extensions.Request().GetAsync();`

`// user.Extensions = extensions;`

Comment: You can access custom attributes via `Expand`, e.g. `.Request().Select(...).Expand("Manager,Extensions").GetAsync();` here we require to query (and fill) manager reference (`Manager`) and our custom attributes (`Extensions`). Then you can address `Extensions` as a property of `User`

Comment: It seems that way may not work properly: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/745

This API call brings additional info on the internal server error caused: 
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{user-id}?$expand=extensions`

Comment: basquiat: code `500` can be misleading; be careful with cases (`Id` and `id`). Here is an working example from my project: `var data = await GraphClient.Users.Request().Expand("Manager,Extensions").Top(pageSize).Select("Id,... other_fields_here ...").GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);`

Comment: I notice you are fetching multiple users while I am fetching a specific one, that´s probably why I get an error. A JSON. serializer error, btw, most likely due to the error message being returned in the JSON format.

Anyhow, reproducing your example, I get rid of errors but don´t get `Extension [IUserExtensionsCollectionPage]` attribute which comes `null`.

Comment: This never was answered, and I am having the same type of issue.  No matter what I put in the select, it is bringing back all fields for a user: 
var result = await _graphClient.Users["xyz"].GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new[] { "Id", "DisplayName", "OnPremisesExtensionAttributes" };
});
return result;